# Does the kernel parameters order matter in QEMU?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm

I'm facing some interesting issues. Changing the order of kernel parameters passed to the `-append`, it changes the outcome.

Running my QEMU VM with the following works:

```
-append "root=/dev/disk/by-id/virtio-rootfs rootflags=rw flatcar.first_boot=1 tsc=reliable no_timer_check= rcupdate.rcu_expedited=1 i8042.direct=1 i8042.dumbkbd=1 i8042.nopnp=1 i8042.noaux=1 noreplace-smp= reboot=k console=hvc0 console=hvc1 cryptomgr.notests= net.ifnames=0 pci=lastbus=0"
```

However, if put the `root=` to the end then it does not work and the root volume is not found so not mounted.

So I'm now wondering. the order does it really matter? And if so there is any logic behind it? Any rules to follow?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your issue, but I would try removing the trailing `=` from the flags that don't require values: `no_timer_check` `noreplace-smp` `cryptomgr.notests` ...other than that, line breaks prehaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved by checking which flags were passed into the system and checking `cat /proc/cmdline` I've found out that that the flags were quoted with double quote so the kernel was failing the parsing